# Xcode8: Usage of image literals in frameworks

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, xcode8

I am currently updating a project to use `image literals`, to enjoy the benefits of non-optional images. The project is importing various frameworks, and the frameworks are containing images.

In the frameworks, we had to declare an extension on `UIImage` to override the initialiser, because it was looking for the image in the wrong bundle. We did something like:

```
extension UIImage {   
    convenience init?(framework_named imageName: String) {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ClassNameInFramework.self)
        self.init(named: imageName, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    }
}
```

I am wanting to use image literals in the framework too, but like before, the literals are looking for the wrong bundle for the image and the **application crashes**.

Does anyone know, how to specify the image literal to which bundle to look for the image?

Comment: Can't specify unfortunately.  The image literals call the `init(named:)` initializer which looks in the main bundle.

Comment: @dan could you might point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 29):

I discovered a pretty simple workaround and was amazed to not find it anywhere on other posts. I wish it could be more elegant, but it's preferable than using the stringly-typed `UIImage(named:in:compatibleWith:)` initializer in my opinion.

We basically take advantage of the `_ExpressibleByImageLiteral` protocol, which is what Xcode uses to determine if a type is expressible by an image literal. It's part of the Swift standard library, but it's hidden from autocompletion, I guess because it's uncommon to want to initialize a custom type with an image literal. However, it's just what we want and behaves exactly like the other `ExpressibleBy` protocols.

```
struct WrappedBundleImage: _ExpressibleByImageLiteral {
    let image: UIImage?

    init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String) {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ClassInFramework.self)
        image = UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    }
}
```

Note that I use a wrapper instead of a `UIImage` subclass, which would seem like a better option. Sadly, classes like `UIImage` are not intended to be subclassed and you will find yourself getting a lot of headaches if you do.

And now its usage becomes:

```
let image = ( as WrappedBundleImage).image
```

Not as concise as a normal image literal, but it's the best we've got for now. We just have to remember to do the `as` casting, otherwise our custom initializer will not get called.

You can also do something like this:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func fromWrappedBundleImage(_ wrappedImage: WrappedBundleImage) -> UIImage? {
        return wrappedImage.image
    }
}
```

And we can now use it like this:

```
UIImage.fromWrappedBundleImage()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution. The only thing that could be an issue is the fact that the default image literals is still visible in the "Media Library" list. This is the list on the bottom right in Xcode. This could result in issues when people use literals from this list because these literals still point to the main Bundle.

Comment: You're right @bartosss, thanks for the comment. I've updated my answer above to use optionals instead, in case we do provide a literal from the main bundle by mistake.

Comment: @diegomontoyas Isn't `_ExpressibleByImageLiteral` technically a private API?

Comment: It is a public protocol https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CompilerProtocols.swift#L939